# "Error: operand out of range" when using PPC assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, powerpc

I have bulit gcc cross compiler/assembler/linker with 'powerpc-eabi' as TARGET in windows using cygwin. When assembling, I am getting the following error ....

```
code/sfiles/init_evh.s: Assembler messages:
code/sfiles/init_evh.s:381: Error: operand out of range (0x0000fffd is not between 0xffff8000 and 0x00007fff)
```

But, in that line number,  the following instruction is there:

```
addi  r2,0,0xFFFD
```

I am using the follwing command for assembly:

```
c:/cygwin/home/cdot/powerpc/bin/powerpc-eabi-as -mbig-endian -m603 -mregnames --
defsym _NDI_=1 --defsym _DBGR_ON_=1 --defsym DEBUG=1 --defsym _PARAM_DEBUG_=1 --
defsym _NIU_=1 -gdwarf-2 -I code/hfiles -o build/niu_ndi_dbgr_init_evh.o code/sf
iles/init_evh.s 2>build/niu_ndi_dbgr_init_evh.err
```

I would like to know why the above error appear.

Please help in this direction.

Comment: Did you write the instruction or was it generated by the compiler? Because if you wrote it, you should simply change it (guessing from the error message I suppose it will accept 0xfffffffd and take the lower two bytes anyway) while if it was generated by the compiler, it would be a bug and you should report it to gcc bug tracker.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler/assembler is correct in emitting an error message here. The use of a constant `0xfffd` is not possible with immediate-type instructions in PPC assembly.

PowerPC immediate instructions (such as the `addi` you're attempting to do) have a generic instruction format 6/5/6/16 bits each for opcode/source/dest/constant; the 16bit constant is *signed*, hence the range is `-32768 ... 32767`; this is *sign extended* to 32bit, which means you'll get a range of `0xffff8000 ... 0x7fff`. See also:

[IBM Developerworks PPC Assembly Introduction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ppc/), particularly "listing 3."

That's what the error message is trying to tell you.